How can I change an array element without rerendering the whole array
How can I avoid the component to rerender when I input new data?
I tried to memoize each cell but it still giving me the same issue. How should I do it?
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";

const Cell = memo(({ value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      className="border-yellow-500 border-2 text-black"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(new Array(2500).fill(""));

  const handleInputChange = (index, value) => {
    const newTest = [...test];
    newTest[index] = value;
    setTest(newTest);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        {test.map((cell, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="border text-dark">
            <Cell
              value={cell}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(index, e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


dont use index as key, fill your array with some data like random numbers and use the number as key.

instead of creating a new array each time a value is type inside the input use the function form of setTest so that it remain immutable and react can compare behind the scene the references to determine if the state has changed
 const handleInputChange = (index, value) => {
  setTest(prevTest => {
  const newTest = [...prevTest];
  newTest[index] = value;
  return newTest;
});

};

It still have performances issues with it

@awfha the performance issue came from the fact that you are rendering 2500 elements at the same time considered implementing list visualisation with library like react-virtualized [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized]  or react-window it will help you manage large list also consider using pagination
